# how to make sure that when parsing yandex does not think that I am not a bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

```
enter code here
url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/? 
text=что%20такое%20уран%20вещество&lr=28&clid=2349563&win=430&src=suggest_B'
user = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.663 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}

full_page = requests.get(url, headers=user)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'lxml')

con = soup.findAll("div" )
print(con)
```

at the first launch, everything was fine, but then it output"...We are sorry, but the requests from your device are similar to automatic ones...."

Comment: ...well, you _are_ a bot aren't you? (Not "you" literally, but your code.) They are perfectly within their rights not to answer your requests, especially if you are breaking their terms of service (I haven't looked at them but I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: of course, my code is a bot, but I just need to get the text from the question using the code ).